# Slim php not working after moving all contents down the tree by one step

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

My previous setup:

```
rootFolder
 -api/slim_app
 -index.html
 -.htaccess
```

My new setup

```
 rootFolder
  -.htaccess
  newFolder
    -api/slim_app
    -index.html
    -.htaccess
```

The new .htaccess file has this in it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^newFolder/ /newFolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?
It worked fine before the move. I did in-depth testing and found out that php slim is not routing correctly and gives 404 when I visit the /api/ urls.

Comment: And what was the previous .htaccess file content?

Comment: You don't need to change the htaccess... restore the default one and you should be fine

Comment: Keep above shown rule in site root .htaccess

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^newFolder/ /newFolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

this is in site root, the in newFolder is unchanged

Comment: @geggleto I have not changed the one in newFolder, but I had to add a new one to rootFolder so it would route correctly